# Batch script to join video and audio files and save according to subfolder name

Tags: batch-file, video, merge

After a conversion process I've thousands files like so:

> - **VideoFolderName0001 - Introduction**
>
>   - video
>
>     - videostream.avi
>   - audio
>
>     - audiostream.mp3
> - **VideoFolderName0002 - History of stackoverflow**
>
>   - video
>
>     - videostream.avi
>   - audio
>
>     - audiostream.mp3
> - **VideoFolderName003 - Before Asking**
>
>   - video
>
>     - videostream.avi
>   - audio
>
>     - audiostream.mp3

How can we merge (or join or combine or mux ..etc) *.avi and *.mp3 files according to (up 2) foldername.

I tried with avidemux one by one. But you know it takes a long time. There should be a cool script to automate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, merge all files:

```
for /d %%a in (VideoFolderName*) do ffmpeg -i "%%~a\videostream.avi" -i "%%~a\audiostream.mp3" -c copy "%%~a\videofile.avi"
```

next build the concatenate file:

```
(for /d %%a in (VideoFolderName*) do echo(file '%%~a\\videofile.avi')>"concat.txt"
```

and last build the concatenated video:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy video.avi
```

You must take care for the correct sequence of the avi files to concatenate.

<sub>[ffmpeg manual](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your first command is good enough for me. There is only a mistake for subfolder: It should be like that **video** \videostream.avi and **audio** \audiostream.mp3 For your second and third command are not working regularly but not important me because I think I was misunderstood. I would like only to join two files, after that no need to join again for all videofile.avi. I also solve rename problem with Bulk Rename Utility. By the way, I want to say again to another newbies: If you're using in CMD try remove one `&` and if you've an issue with character encoding use `chcp 650001`